# ifconfig wlan0 shows fetching interface information: Device not found

Tags: linux, wifi, ifconfig

When I enter the command:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

it says:

```
wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely your wireless interface is not called wlan0. Many distributions that use `systemd` now use "stateless persistent network interface naming", meaning that a particular device will retain its interface name even if you change the hardware in your machine.

This means the old names like `eth0` and `wlan0` can no longer be used, so there is a new naming scheme.

Use `ifconfig -a` to figure out what interface names are being used.

Comment: You should also mention that `ip` is the more modern replacement of `ifconfig`, so it should be used instead. `ip link` shows all links, `ip addr` shows the assigned IP addresses.

Comment: @dirkt I personally don't use ```ip```. If you want to make an answer that uses ```ip```, go for it.